# Feature detection

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure if there is an Android way to do this or if this is just a general Java question. What is the best design for a feature detection mechanism? I want to be able to ask if the runtime environment supports feature foo (this may be determined at compile time as well, so not just runtime stuff).

UPDATE

I'm thinking of using the following (naive?) approach:

```
public enum Feautures {
    GPS, DockToKeyboard;

    public boolean isSupported() {
        //switch statement
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(
            RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
if (activities.size()>0); // then you have SPEECH RECOGNIZER.
```

or

```
final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)); // then you have GPS.
```

Comment: Thanks ahmet, this is useful however I'm looking for a way to wrap this so it's at a higher level than what you're doing here. Some features are not going to be provided by the Android API.

Comment: What are those features? Give some example.

Comment: For example if the application is running on a Nook then I want to the LOW_RES feature to be true, if it's running on a phone I want it to be false.

Comment: Or, if another application is installed (NookHelper.apk), I want the NookHelperAvailable feature to be true.

Comment: You should write a long wrapper for all those. There are ways but not one unified method.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to get some best practice for doing so from a more experience Android developer.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_AUDIO_LOW_LATENCY

Comment: Thanks for the references however I'm looking for a way to wrap this so it's at a higher level than what's described here. Some features are not going to be provided by the Android API.